# How to change desktop settings back after using gksudo nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, gksu

When I use `gksudo nautilus` to browse folders that are owned by root, my Ubuntu desktop returns to some kind of default setting - changing my wallpaper and displaying desktop icons (which I don't usually display). However, without manually changing the settings, I cannot find a way to make the settings return to my own preferences after closing the root file browser.

Is there any way to do this? I tried quitting then restarting Nautilus from the terminal but that doesn't work.

Note: I am using Ubuntu 10.04.

**Edit:** At Scaine's request, here is the output of `gksudo nautilus`:

```
(gksudo:20400): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory scalable/places/mimetypes of theme Se-interface-green has no size field


(gksudo:20400): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory scalable/devices/scalable/emblems of theme Se-interface-green has no size field

Initializing nautilus-gdu extension
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 0.6.7
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  Can you try running sudo nautilus from a terminal and posting any output you see there?

Comment: not that it should make a difference, but try not using gksudo, and use gksu instead.

Comment: Err, gksudo is a symbolic link to gksu.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like somehow nautilus is running as root and replacing yourdesktop. Normally this should not happen.

However, here is a likely solution. Use:

`gksu nautilus --no-desktop`

when launching nautilus as root.

If you get the problem of your desktop being altered as before, run:

`gksu killall nautilus`

or from a terminal:

`sudo killall nautilus`

.

Comment: Tried the killall command from terminal and it didn't do anything. When I tried the no-desktop command, I get an error "Could find /home/username/no-desktop"

Comment: try it again, I had an error in my answer.

Comment: No change with the killall commands again. And when trying `--no-desktop` it outputs an error: "gksu: unrecognised option '--no-desktop'"

Comment: this should be the proper solution. the "problem" is nautilus's default nature of displaying the launching user's desktop. disable it by using the --no-desktop parameter when you first use gksudo nautilus --no-desktop

Comment: are you running `gksu --no-desktop`? instead of `gksu *nautilus* --no-desktop`? You run --no-desktop alone...

Answer (score 0):

This should never happen however

To resolve you can restart nautilus

Open the Terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) and type

```
nautilus -q
```

Then hit `enter`